# Floating relay terminal in AC circuit causing simulation error

Tags: ac, relay, simulation, switching, dimmer

I'm trying to switch between two branches for my circuit. But as the relay switches, the other terminal is left floating. In an AC circuit, I cannot use a pull-down resistor.

I also have a feeling that this connection might lead to a disaster in real life. How can I resolve this problem?

Explanation of circuit: Basically, the relay switches to a different branch depending on the input on the base of the transistor. Each branch intends to provide a different resistance level.

Perhaps there is a better configuration to carry out my intended idea?

[image]

full schematic:
[image]

I also seem to get a simulation error when I try to switch on and off a lightbulb circuit using a 555 timer and a relay. I suspect the problem might be similar.

[image]

Comment: you do not  need both R3 and R5 in first schematic ... only one resistor is needed, because both resistors  have the same value

Comment: To make the simulator happy, tie a 1 Gohm resistor between any floating nodes and ground. It will have no measurable effect on the behavior of the circuit.